# powershell script to play a music folder on windows startup

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-7, autoplay

How to use powershell to autoplay a folder of mp3 files using Windows Media Player on Windows 7 startup. I figure that there are two aspects: 1) the script must run automatically when Windows starts up 2) the script must call Media Player to open the folder and play the files therein

Comment: What have you tried?  This isn't a place to come ask for people to write stuff for you.  Break it down. You want a script to run on login, maybe scheduled tasks. You want to start a media player with a list of files... How do you get files in Powershell?  How do you send files to a media player over the command line. Maybe you even need to build a playlist file...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could make a playlist from that folder in Windows Media Player.

Then you could call windows media player with a commandline switch, which tells it to open and play a certain playlist. You can find some information on commandline switches for WMP here:
[http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1389/windows-media-player-wmp-11-command-line-options/]

When that is done, you would create a scheduled job, to fire your WMP script every time you log on.
Information for that part can be found here:
[https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993(v=ws.11).aspx]